# Is it possible to use npm to render jade first and then use the html files in apache?

Tags: java, node.js, apache, pug

I am trying to use latest jade pre-processor with apache, is it possible to use node server to render the jade files to html inside Java application and then host the Java application in apache??

Answer (score 0):

(Jade is now Pug.)

You can use pug-cli to pre-process pug files into HTML.

https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli